# computer booting then reporting no drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd

Im having a very odd problem with a windows computer.
bios reports 2 nvme ssds in raid 0, leaving bios the computer will boot into windows and will fully enter windows (past sign-in page) but after a minute or two the screen will go black and report no bootable drives.
if i run onboard diagnostics, it reports there are no drives, but when i exit and click "exit and reboot" i am booted straight into windows, well after booting for 2-3 minutes.

I have a feeling that one of the drives is in the process of failing but i dont know a failure that would let the drive work for 15-90 minutes. i have tried defragging or crystal disk info but the system dies before the scan is able to finish

Comment: Defrag gives no benefit, and causes excessive wear on SSDs; do not use it on any modern drive. What is hosting your RAID? Is it hardware, or software, your BIOS, or an add-in card? Please edit your question to add requested info.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As you state, a failing drive could cause that issue. Specifically, Windows must be able to **write** to it's partition, and as an SSD fails, it may become **read-only** to prevent further damage, i.e., allow data to be recovered. **Make images of both drives now**, because diagnosis can wait, but saving data cannot.

Comment: Doesn't sound good, so I suggest to ensure your backups are good. You could add screenshots of the SMART data of your disks for analysis. If you don't have a product for that, try [speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) (Storage section), if it works on Windows 7.